# How can I query data from Table A while using Table B credentials?

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing a mobile application which can record attendance. I develop it so that two different app (for staff and student) can access same database (Google Firebase Realtime Database). I had named both of the table as student and staff.
My problem is, when I login as a staff, I cannot query data that being stored as student. 
How can I do it?

This is how i save student data.

```
    private void saveData() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Student");

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(userName, userIDNum, userICNum, userEmail, userPhone, userCollegeName, userRoom, userFurniture);
    myRef.push().setValue(userProfile);}
```

this is how i save staff data.

```
    private void saveData() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Staff");

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(userName, userIDNum, userICNum, userEmail, userPhone, userCollegeName, userRoom, userFurniture);
    myRef.push().setValue(userProfile);
}
```

[how my firebase db looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdBd1.png)

problems that I get

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.asus.courest.ViewStudentRecord.onCreate(ViewStudentRecord.java:39)
```

this are my coding to retrieve the data
[coding for retrieving data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZqD.png)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Create a student Model class in Teachers app similar to the Model class of students in Students app,
get a reference of Student table from firebase and access the data by using Child

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Student")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Student stud = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                        if (stud.getRoll().equals(roll)) {
                             //whatever you want
                        } else {
                            //show some error
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi Mavee, I used your suggested example but there are some error occurs.

Comment: Nope. Instead of null error. it says that I'm trying to declare the "Student.class"

Comment: You aren't using my code exactly right?  You've to change it to suit your needs

Comment: yeah. i'm not totally using your code. instead of Student, im using UserProfile class to store data.

Comment: You've two tables. "Student" and "staff". When accessing one you've to get the db reference of that particular one and get the data(class) in respective class. I dunno how you naming the classes and all but the code above should work i believe

Comment: i had added my query coding in the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
   myRef.child("Events").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("event_Name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("startEvent") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("eventOrganizer")))) ) {
                String event_name = dataSnapshot.child("event_Name").getValue().toString();
                Activity_Event_Name.setText(event_name);


                String startEvent = dataSnapshot.child("startEvent").getValue().toString();
                ActivityStartDateInput.setText(startEvent);

                String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("eventOrganizer").getValue().toString();
                ActivityCityInput.setText(fullname);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```